# Paging issue in views when implements node access

Tags: views, paging

I have created a content type called **Details** it is the collection of employees detail. And also I have created a Taxonomy terms called **manager**, **employee**, **lead**. Also I have created a field(as Taxonomy reference) for user profile to indicate whether she/he is **manager** or **lead** or **employee**. Now I want to put the restriction based on the user. I have achieve the restriction using my custom module. The codes are below:

```
    function my_module_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  global $user;
  $user_obj = user_load($account->uid);
  if (isset($node->type) && ($node->type == 'details') && ($op == 'view')) {
        if (($user->uid == 0) || ($user_obj->field_user_company['und'][0]['tid'] != $node->field_company['und'][0]['tid'])){
            return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
        }       
    }  
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

The above code simply do, if the node taxonomy term, and the user field taxonomy term is same then he will perfectly access to the nodes. I got struggle with views. I have created a view to show the node title that can be access by the user. **Manager** has 100 nodes to view, in views settings I have enable the pager, 25 items per page to display. Pager splits into 4 page and shows correctly. But when comes to **employee** user he has access to 1 node only, but in views it still shows the pager in 4 parts.

```
function my_module_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  if (($view->name == 'views1') || ($view->name == 'views2')) {
        $nids = array();
      foreach($view->result as $key=>$result) {
          $nids[$key] = $result->nid;
      }
      $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
      foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            if (!node_access('view',$node)) {
                $key = array_search($node->nid, $nids);

                unset($view->result[$key]);
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

The views pager display must be changed dynamically depends on the number of nodes. Is anyone knows kindly show me a right path to achieve this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hook_node_access() doesn't really do any access checks on node listings or views.

To get this to work you should look into implementing [hook_node_grants()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants/7) and [hook_node_access_records()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records/7)

That logic will be included in your views query so you could get rid of hook_views_post_execute()